# How to get values from json object to php array

Tags: php, arrays, json, object

I am writing a php file for an application that allows the user to print a project report (with fpdf library).

The aim is to get datas from a db and then to build the PDF file dynamically.

The datas are stored in json.

It is ok for almost all datas, but there are some that I can't reach.
Here is an example :
First of all I already did this :

```
$Array['roof_coordinates'] = json_decode($Array['roof_coordinates'], false);
```

To get the number "nb" of "A523500" I'm doing like that :

```
$Array['roof_coordinates']->results->packingList->total->A523500->nb;
```

What am I doing wrong ?

```
  "roofCoordinates": {

    "results": {

      "packingList": {

        "total": {

          "A523500": {

            "ref": "STRA523500",
            "nb": 16

          },
          "A523120": {

            "ref": "STRA523120",
            "nb": 0

          },
          "A522100": {

            "ref": "STRA522100",
            "nb": 8

          },

        },

      }

    },

}
```

And I tried to pass "true" to json_decode to convert objects to associative array but it doesn't seems to work...

Any help will be great !
Thank you in advance ;)

Comment: Have you tried adding the `roofCoordinates` level - `$Array['roof_coordinates']->roofCoordinates->results->packingList->total->A523500->nb;`

Comment: But what problem do you have? Are you getting any PHP error? The value doesn't match the expected value?

Comment: What is the output of  var_dump($Array['roof_coordinates']->results->packingList->total->A523500->nb)???

Comment: Hi thanks for the answers. 
The output is 0 instead of 16.

Comment: I don't have any php errors. Just not the good value, and if I try with "ref", I don't have any output.

Comment: Don't know if it can help but when I try to serialize it, it gives me :
O:8:"stdClass":1:{s:11:"packingList";O:8:"stdClass":2:{s:5:"total";O:8:"stdClass":10:{s:6:"OPPONT";O:8:"stdClass":2:{s:2:"nb";i:0;s:3:"ref";s:0:"";}s:6:"STFIXA";O:8:"stdClass":2:{s:2:"nb";i:0;s:3:"ref";s:0:"";}s:6:"STINNA";O:8:"stdClass":2:{s:2:"nb";i:0;s:3:"ref";s:0:"";}s:7:"A522100";O:8:"stdClass":2:{s:2:"nb";i:0;s:3:"ref";s:0:"";}s:7:"A523120";O:8:"stdClass":2:{s:2:"nb";i:0;s:3:"ref";s:0:"";}s:7:"A523500";O:8:"stdClass":2:{s:2:"nb";i:0;s:3:"ref";s:0:"";}s:7:"OPCAPSA";O:8:"stdClass":2:}}

Comment: That looks as though there are a few levels different, try `$Array['roof_coordinates']->packingList->total->A523500->nb;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are accessing the resulting data structure correctly, it should work whether you decode to an array or an object.

```
<?php
$json = <<<END
{
  "roofCoordinates": {
    "results": {
      "packingList": {
        "total": {
          "A523500": {
            "ref": "STRA523500",
            "nb": 16
          },
          "A523120": {
            "ref": "STRA523120",
            "nb": 0
          },
          "A522100": {
            "ref": "STRA522100",
            "nb": 8
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
END;

$arrayResults = json_decode($json, true);
$nbFromArray = $arrayResults['roofCoordinates']['results']['packingList']['total']['A523500']['nb'];

$stdClassResults = json_decode($json);
$nbFromStdClass =  $stdClassResults->roofCoordinates->results->packingList->total->A523500->nb;

assert($nbFromArray==16, 'Value should equal 16');
assert($nbFromArray==$nbFromStdClass, 'Values from either json_decode method should be equal');

echo 'From array: '.$nbFromArray.PHP_EOL;
echo 'From stdClass: '.$nbFromStdClass.PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: You are right, it works.
The structure (and yours) is good. The problem was coming from the db itself... In fact when I tried to get the json values on frontend with console.log() it gaves me the good values, but after an calculation ! 
The thing is that the app is not saving the values after calcuations yet. Really sorry it.
And thank you again ;)